# Can we use Amazon's iOS SDK v2 in live apps while it is still in developer preview?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, sdk

I am curious if anyone is using the new AWS sdk in production. Currently version 2 of the SDK is in 'Developer Preview': http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ios/

From a legal perspective:
I can't find anything online that says it is illegal to use it, but I know that Apple's iOS sdk developer previews are highly proprietary so I wanted to check.

From a stability perspective:
We are trained to be wary of using anything that is still in preview or beta stage, but then again this is Amazon so I'm hoping basic functionality should be considered stable even during the developer preview stage.  I am planning to use the SDK for some not-too-fancy simple S3 upload/download calls. I'm curious if anyone has run into any stability issues and if it is safe to include v2 of the sdk in my app.

Answer (score 1):

It's available under the APACHE license so yes you can use it in live apps.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v2/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: Thanks Bennie...any thoughts on the stability concern?